# contains is not a member of std::map MSVC

Tags: c++, dictionary, visual-c++

When attempting to use the c++ 20 feature [std::map::contains()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) within visual studio 2017 with `/std:c++latest` enabled, the compiler is still unable to locate the contains() member of std::map. Is this not yet available for MSVC or am I doing something wrong? Basic example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,char> example = {{1,'a'},{2,'b'}};

    if(example.contains(2)) {
        std::cout << "Found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```

**Results in:**

```
>main.cpp
1>c:\dev\random_cpp\random_cpp\main.cpp(11): error C2039: 'contains': is not a member of 'std::map<int,char,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=int,
1>            _Ty=char
1>        ]
```

Comment: Well, a compiler that was released in 2017 is not very likely to have features from a C++ version that would not be finalized until 2020.

Comment: Why not upgrade to VS2019? It [seems to work](https://godbolt.org/z/87NyZq) there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik LOL that does sound logical. It's possible I just misunderstand what `/std:c++latest` is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019) the method `std::map::contains` is only available as of VS 2019 16.1.

Comment: Fix: in Visual Studio, update C++ Language Standard to: `ISO C++20 Standard (/std:c++20)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not implemented yet in the Microsoft STL version shipped with VS2017. But you can emulate it using std::map::count() - if count() returns nonzero, key is present, if zero - not present.